# D3.js: Mouseover is not triggered on zoomed topojson features

Tags: d3.js, zooming, mouseover, topojson

I have a US map in topojson format.  Users select the state and counties from 
dropdownlists.  When a user selects the county, the map zooms in to the selected
county.

To do:  I need to display the county name when users mouseover the county.  I'm
able to do this when the map is first loaded but not when the features are zoomed in.

I'm using a tooltip to display text on mouseover.  Following is my code: (A sample version can be viewed at:  https://realtimeceap.brc.tamus.edu).

```
<script>
//globals: create tooptip div
var div = d3.select("body").append("xhtml:div")
    .attr("id", "divTip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

function zoomToCounty(stname, cnty) {
    d3.json("/topo/us-wgs84.json", function (us) {
        var conus = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties);

        //initialize selected county text
        d3.select("text").remove();

        //reset active to inactive size and color            
        d3.select("#svgMap2").select("#counties").select(".active")
            .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")
            .style("stroke", "#808080");

            //initialize rect
            svg.select("rect").remove();

            //zoom to selected county
            d3.selectAll(".county")
                .classed("active", function (d) {
                    if (d.properties.StateName === stname && d.properties.County === cnty) {
                        svg.append("rect")
                            .attr("class", "overlay")
                            .attr("width", width)
                            .attr("height", height)
                            .call(d3.zoom()
                                .scaleExtent([.05, 8])
                                .on("zoom", moveWheel))

                        //zoom in to max scale extent
                        var zoom_in = d3.zoom()
                            .scaleExtent([.05, 8])
                            .on("zoom", zoomedIn);

                        //get path of selected county
                        var bounds = path.bounds(d),
                            dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
                            dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
                            x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
                            y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
                            scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height))),
                            translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

                        //add text at coordinates inside a group
                        d3.select("#svgMap2").select("#counties")
                            .append("text")
                                .style("fill", "black")
                                .style("font-size", "20px")
                                .attr("x", width / 2)   //center the text
                                .attr("y", height / 2)
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  //set anchor y justification
                            .text($("#countySelect").val());                            

                        d3.select("#svgMap2").select("#counties")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(1000)
                            .call(zoom_in.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(translate[0], translate[1]).scale(scale));  //center  

                        return true;
            }
        });

        //hover over counties
        d3.select("#counties").selectAll(".county")             
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("name", function (d) { return d.properties.County; }, true)                
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.FIPS; }, true)
            .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")     //inactive border width
            .on("mouseover", function () {
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("stroke", "#ff5800");
                div.transition()
                    .duration(300)
                div.text(function () {
                    if (d.properties.StateName === stname && d.properties.County === cnty) {
                        return $("#countySelect").val();
                    } else {
                        return d.properties.County;
                    }
                })
                    .style("opacity", 1)
                    .style("class", "label")
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) - 10 + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) - 5 + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function () {
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("stroke", "#808080");
                div.transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("opacity", 0);
            });

    }); //end d3.json
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.  I needed to "attach" the mouseover code on the "rect".  I replaced the codes on "hover over counties" portion as follows:

```
    //initialize rect
    svg.select("rect").remove();

    //hover over counties   
    d3.selectAll(".county", function (d) {
        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([.05, 8])
                .on("zoom", moveWheel))
                .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .style("stroke", "#ff5800")
                    div.transition().duration(300)
                    div.text(function (d) { return conus.features[i].properties.County })
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                        .style("class", "label")
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) - 10 + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) - 5 + "px");
                })
                .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                    div.transition().duration(300)
                        .style("opacity", 0);
                })
    });
```